# Android - Values Depending on Language & Screen Size

Tags: android, android-resources

Please excuse my bad English, I'm French!

In my Android project, I want to have different values for both languages (es and fr) AND screen sizes. I can't find anything about that. Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Android allows you to provide alternate resources depending on the configuration of the device the app is running on. In your case, you will need to provide:

1. Different `String` resources translated for the languages supported.
2. Different `layout` resources optimized for the screen sizes supported.
3. Different density image resources for the screen densities supported.

The Android docs cover these topics quite well:

- [How to handle providing these alternate resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)
- [How to access and use resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)
- [How to localize your application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

These docs should give you an in depth guide on what you need to do to properly structure your app.

Comment: This is also in the documentation, but it's important enough that it's worth noting here:  if you want to use a particular resource only for "large screens with french language", you can add more qualifiers to the directory names.  For example:  `layout-fr-large` or `values-fr-large`.

Comment: That is true, however that is a very rare (and strange) use case, and I would strongly recommend against suggesting that to the OP. The docs cover multiple identifiers with more realistic use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

For french, put your Strings.xml file in values-fr